# No Export Format Working For IK Rig

Tags: export

I tried the most common export format FBX and DAE and OBJ but none of them work when i test try to import them back into blender. I read the documentation https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/data_system/files/import_export.html and it claims that FBX would work for rigs. I'm using IK rig. What format should i use instead? I noticed that most people can publish several formats online, how did they accomplish that?

Comment: There are no formats that's supports constraints.

Comment: hmmm that's interesting. i uploaded my model at https://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/1875020 but only attached the .blend file so i guess that is the only or best approach?